# PHP T string error for sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a strange error with my PHP code. it says there is a unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error, but I simply can't see it.

```
    $dateResult = mysqli_query($connection, 'select county, cuisine,
    count(*) from inspection, restaurant where inspection.rid = 
    restaurant.rid and inspection.passfail = ''PASS'' and idate like '$date%' 
    group by county, cuisine');
```

I'm assuming its an issue with either my like pattern '$date%' or with 'PASS'.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the `'`s... Use them properly. `"select county, cuisine,
    count(*) from inspection, restaurant where inspection.rid = 
    restaurant.rid and inspection.passfail = 'PASS' and idate like '$date%' 
    group by county, cuisine"`

Comment: I think i've tried every combination. I also tried "PASS", but to no avail.

Comment: If `$date` is not a static value in your code you are open to SQL injections. Look into prepared statements. php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this your are conflicting `'` and `"`

```
 $dateResult = mysqli_query($connection, "select county, cuisine,
    count(*) from inspection, restaurant where inspection.rid = 
    restaurant.rid and inspection.passfail = 'PASS' and idate like '$date%' 
    group by county, cuisine");
```

Comment: Also, use explicit `join` notation instead of deprecated pre-ANSI implicit notation.

Comment: wow, I can't believe this. I really need to read up on the differences between mysql and mysqli. 
why is the explicit join better though? isn't it equivalent?